# Delete duplicate rows but keep the earliest row (by date criteria) - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete

I have this table and three columns (ID, Email, [Last Update].

I want to delete duplicate emails but keep the last updated row (by date criteria). In this example, `aaa` is duplicated. It has 1 row in 2011 and other in 2014. I want to keep just 2014.

```
ID       Email          Last update         
a-4        aaa           10/01/2011 
b-1        bbb           10/02/2012    
k-1        ccc           05/03/2013    
d-9        aaa           10/08/2014
t-7        bbb           02/09/2015
```

Comment: which sql server are you using? oracle? ms sql? my sql?

Comment: I think register means a record.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server you can use `CTE` to perform the `DELETE`:

```
;WITH ToDelete AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email         
                             ORDER BY [Last update] DESC) AS rn
   FROM mytable
)
DELETE FROM ToDelete
WHERE rn > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell us which DBMS you are using, but the following is ANSI SQL and should work on all (modern) DBMS:

```
delete from the_table
where exists  (select id
               from the_table t2
               where t2.email = the_table.email
                 and t2.id <> the_table.id
                 and t2.last_update > the_table.last_update);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ca442/1

Answer (score 1):

Use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT First(ID) AS Id, First(Email) AS Email, Max([Last update]) AS LastUpd
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Email
ORDER BY Max([Last update]) DESC;
```

and `MAKE TABLE` upon necessity.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the duplicated records for the email field:

```
DELETE a FROM MyTable a INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Email, MAX([Last Update]) [Last Update]
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY Email
) b ON a.Email = b.Email AND a.[Last Update] <> b.[Last Update];
```